# Scaling Rails with Cache-on-write

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, scalability

I currently have a rails app that uses the traditional caching.  `cache do` blocks are used to cache slow-rendering partials.  This works great for the most part, except for a few pages which take too long to render on the first read.

I'd like to move the rendering of these partials to the write-side from the read-side, by rendering in either the model or in sweepers when the underlying data changes.  Preferably, this would be in the sweepers that already invalidate the cache keys.  Is this a good approach?  Is there a "right" way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it the actual partial that is taking a while to render or the queries required to actually get the data?  If it's the latter you're better off caching those in a write-through manner, it might be simpler than trying to update cached partials on write.